# in R, how to make each dataframe generated in foreach loops available in global environment

Tags: r, foreach, global, environment

In R, how to make each dataframe generated in foreach loop available as individual dataframes in global environment

I was only able to save them into a list (x), but the list is of 3 layers; there are over 40,000 dataframes, and unpacking them is very time consuming.

```
x <- foreach(q=1:countq, .export = ls(globalenv())) %do% {
        foreach(p=1:countp, .export = ls(globalenv())) %do% {
          foreach(o=1:countero, .export = ls(globalenv())) %dopar% {
            n<-rbind(df_o, df_p, df_q)
          }
        }
```

It would be nice to have dataframes n1, n2, n3, ... till n40000 from this nested foreach loop.

Comment: You won't get far trying to access variables in one R session's environment from another R session. And while I understand the difficulty of dealing with multi-tier lists-of-lists, I suggest your question should have less (nothing?) to do with `foreach` and all about "nested-lists". Perhaps if you provide an example (maybe 2-3 simple triple-nested lists), we can help with the aggregation and/or extraction you need. (For that, we'll also need to know what you need from them, i.e., expected output.)

Comment: For a good sample of data, I suggest using the output of `dput`, perhaps something like `mt <- mtcars[1:2,]; dput(replicate(3, replicate(2, replicate(2, mt, simplify=F), simplify=F), simplify=FALSE))`. Just a thought, the key is `dput(head(x))` where `x` is your nested-list.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be easy to use once you convert your list of lists of lists of data.frames into a single data.frame, e.g., with `data.table::rbindlist`.

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel( cores = 2 )
countq <- countp <- countero <- 30
d <- mtcars
x <- 
foreach(q=1:countq) %do% {
    foreach(p=1:countp) %do% {
        foreach(o=1:countero) %dopar% {
            data.frame( q=q, p=p, o=o, d )
        }
    }
}
x <- lapply( x, function(u) lapply(u, data.table::rbindlist) )
x <- lapply( x, data.table::rbindlist )
x <- data.table::rbindlist(x)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
```